# Vue.js axios get request failed with error status code 404

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, axios, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I am using view.js as the frontend and making get request to backend in asp.net core and it is resulting in 404 error as I mentioned before.
All the code I am mentioning here is giving same error:

```
getProducts() {
     this.loading = true;
     axios.get('/Products')
         .then(res => {
             console.log(res);
             this.products = res.data;
         })
         .catch(err => {
             console.log(err);
         })
         .then(() => {
             this.loading = false;
         });
 },
 createProduct() {
     this.loading = true;
     axios.post('/Products', this.productModel)
         .then(res => {
             console.log(res.data);
             this.products.push(res.data);
         })
         .catch(err => {
             console.log(err);
         })
         .then(() => {
             this.loading = false;
             this.editing = false;
         });
 }
```

Here is my ProductsController.cs class

```
 [Route("[controller]")]
    [Authorize(Policy = "Manager")]
    public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _ctx;

        public ProductsController(ApplicationDbContext ctx)
        {
            _ctx=ctx;
        }

        [HttpGet("")]
        public IActionResult GetProductsAdmin() => Ok(new GetProductsAdmin(_ctx).Do());

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult GetProduct(int id) => Ok(new GetProduct(_ctx).Do(id));

        [HttpPost("")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateProduct([FromBody] CreateProduct.Request request) => Ok(await new CreateProduct(_ctx).Do(request));

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteProduct(int id) => Ok(await new DeleteProduct(_ctx).Do(id));



        [HttpPut("")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProduct([FromBody] UpdateProduct.Request request) => Ok(await new UpdateProduct(_ctx).Do(request));
    }
}
```

The problem is that the controller action method is not being hit when get or create request is made I have tried using breakpoints.
I have used the same logic for the StockController.cs and in stock.js it is working good.
Can please anyone help.

Comment: first step of a 404 is verifying the request URL is correct, and that information (both expected vs. actual) you have not provided.

Comment: @yoduh I am making get request to following action method  axios.get('/Products')
ProductsController/ProductsAdmin

Comment: @yoduh the url iam sending get request to is https://localhost:7148/Products and it is correct i have tried it using postman api

Comment: The actual outbound request generated from `axios.get('/Products')` can be seen by checking your browser's dev tools network tab. What is the URL that is actually attached to the request? Is it the expected URL?